# Run script on Azure VM Scale Set when deprovisioning

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a VMSS in Azure that manually scales up and down based on certain commands in DevOps Pipelines. I already have a script that executes when it is provisioned and that works fine. I want to also execute a script when the VM is deprovisioned, shut down, or deleted.

If it were based on shutdown, I could probably do it with a scheduled task, but it seems like when the Scale Set scales down it essentially pulls the plugs on the machine. It doesn't look like it would wait for a scheduled task to complete, but I can't find any documentation on this.

Since I do manually control the steps to scale down, I can execute commands beforehand. Ideally I would use something like Run Command (I'm not even sure if that is possible with scale set VMs), but the VMs in the scale set are not publicly accessible.

Comment: Out of curiosity (at the moment), what would you like this script to do? If it's something that interacts with another system, I can see where you're going. If it's to do something strictly local to that VM, I'd ask if it matters, because that VM will get scrapped?

Comment: The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-terminate-notification suggests you need to enable Instance Termination notification - I link the document (I know, poor form) because there's a fair amount of detail there.

Comment: Yes, this is for DevOps agents and I want them to remove themselves from DevOps before they shut down. The generated name for the agent just shows as disconnected forever and has to manually be removed. There’s a simple and quick command I can execute in powershell that does it, just not sure how/when to do it.

Comment: This definitely looks like what I need, @WaitingForGuacamole. If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You're using a VMSS Agent Pool already? Because register and unregister are then handled for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-terminate-notification suggests the following (assuming that you are standing up the scale set in the portal):

> 1. Go to Virtual machine scale sets.
> 2. Select + Add to create a new scale set.
> 3. Go to the Management tab.
> 4. Locate the Instance termination section.
> 5. For Instance termination notification, select On.
> 6. For Termination delay (minutes), set the desired default timeout.
> 7. When you are done creating the new scale set, select Review + create button.

Once enabled, a Scheduled Events notification API is available at http://169.254.169.254/metadata/scheduledevents?api-version=2019-01-01 (if your VM is VNet-enabled, which it should be), which you poll with frequency shorter than the termination delay (by enough to give you time to spin down the agent). That API will return a result like the following to tell you that you need to spin down:

```json
{
    "DocumentIncarnation": {IncarnationID},
    "Events": [
        {
            "EventId": {eventID},
            "EventType": "Terminate",
            "ResourceType": "VirtualMachine",
            "Resources": [{resourceName}],
            "EventStatus": "Scheduled",
            "NotBefore": {timeInUTC},
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, with ALL of that in mind, proper termination of an Azure Pipelines SHOULD be baked in to the agent - do you have the setting enabled on the scale set agent pool to retain a problematic agent? If so, that could leave VMs around. If not, perhaps a ticket with Microsoft.

I don't think your approach is wrong, rather, I don't think you should HAVE to resort to this.